# Python NameError using conditional statements (Newbie)

Tags: python, input, python-2.x

Python Newbie here (First day learning).

I'm using Python 2 and using the following if statement code:

```
meaty = input('Do you eat meat? (y/n):')

if meaty == 'y':
    print 'Here is the meaty menu...'
else:
    print 'Here is the veggie menu...'
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "if_elif.py", line 11, in <module>
    meaty = str(input('Do you eat meat? (y/n):'))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'y' is not defined
```

The tutorial I'm following is using Python3 but I'm using Python 2 so maybe that can explain this error?

Thanks guys

Comment: Use `raw_input()`, not `input()`, on Python 2. Better still: if you are learning the language, start with Python 3. Python 2 is a legacy release now.

Comment: Thanks that worked!!! The course I'm learning machine learning from is teaching in Python 2.7 that's why I installed 2.7 using Anaconda but I'll definitely start using Python 3 after this course is complete.